# C++ WinSock2 wait until client sends data

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I have a multi-thread socket server that is supposed to have a continous conversation with the client, so I put my `recv` in a `while(true)` to keep the connection going until one of the sides closes it. The problem I have is when a client is not sending anything, the server keeps trying to recieve data which eventually causes it to crash because it reads from nothing, so I want to know if there is a way to make `recv` stop until there is actual data to recive.

Here is the code to the function that handles a client's connection:

```cpp
void Communicator::clientHandler(SOCKET client)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            char codeBuff[1];
            recv(client, codeBuff, 1, 0);
            int code = static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(codeBuff[0]));
            char lengthBuff[4];
            recv(client, lengthBuff, 4, 0);
            int dataLength = lengthBuff[0] << 24 | lengthBuff[1] << 16 | lengthBuff[2] << 8 | lengthBuff[3];
            char* dataBuff = new char(dataLength);
            recv(client, dataBuff, dataLength, 0);
            dataBuff[dataLength - 1] = 0;

            std::vector<char> dataVec(dataBuff, dataBuff + dataLength);
            Request r = {
                code,
                std::time(nullptr),
                dataVec
            };

            std::copy(dataVec.begin(), dataVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "")); // For debug purposes, prints infintiely

            IRequestHandler* handler = nullptr;
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m_clientsMu);
                handler = m_clients.find(client)->second;
            }

            if (handler->isRequestRelevant(r))
            {
                RequestResult res = handler->handleRequest(r);
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m_clientsMu);
                    delete[] m_clients.find(client)->second;
                    m_clients.find(client)->second = res.newHandler;
                }
                send(client, &res.response[0], res.response.size(), 0);
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorResponse res = { "Invalid request type" };
                std::vector<char> packet = JsonPacketSerializer::serializeResponse(res);
                send(client, &packet[0], packet.size(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        closesocket(client);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Some basic python code I use to test the server:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
s.send(bytes([101, 0, 0, 0, 40, 123, 34, 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100, 34, 58, 34, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 34,
              44, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 116, 101, 115, 116, 34, 125]))
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* dataBuff = new char(dataLength);
```

This creates *one* `char`, most probably with the value `dataLength & 255` and `dataBuff` will be pointing at that *one* `char`. You allocate an array of `char` like this:

```
char* dataBuff = new char[dataLength];
```

You must also free the memory later:

```
delete[] dataBuff;
```

You also need to take care of the return value from `recv` which is the number of bytes received (or `SOCKET_ERROR` to indicate error).

Comment: Thanks! I added a statement to check for the return value of `recv` and fixed the declaration of `dataBuff`

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. Note that I changed `-1` to `SOCKET_ERROR`. I was in a Linux mindset first. Windows uses `SOCKET_ERROR` (which is probably the same thing, but I'm not sure).

Comment: It is the same, but I used `SOCKET_ERROR`